# Remove Environment in Conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

I somehow installed miniconda and miniconda3.
Now `conda env list` looks like

```
base           /home/miniconda
env1           /home/miniconda/envs/env1
env2           /home/miniconda/envs/env2
               /home/miniconda3
               /home/miniconda3/envs/env3
            *  /home/miniconda3/envs/env4
```

How can I manage conda environments now?

How to remove env4 conda environment

Comment: Which part of this question is not covered by the (easily accessible) official documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 9):

Looks like "env4" is activated.. To deactivate use,

`conda deactivate`

After that, you can use this command to remove any environment. ENV_NAME=env4

```
conda env remove --name ENV_NAME
```

Or simply just go to the path

```
/home/miniconda3/envs/
```

and delete 'env4' from there.